# Wildfly 10: EJB Remote Calling stop working when migrating from Wildfly 9 to 10

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, wildfly-10

the following code snippet works without problems calling to a Wildfly 9 server instance, but when it calls to a wildfly 10 server, fails saying:

> WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 192.168.1.47:8080
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:94)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    Properties props;

    props = new Properties();

    props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    props.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", true);
    props.put("endpoint.name","client-endpoint");

    props.put("endpoint.remote.connectionprovider.create.options"
                    + ".org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", false);

    props.put("remote.connections", "default");
    props.put("remote.connection.default.host", "192.168.1.47");
    props.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");

    props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options"
                  + ".org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", false);

    props.put("remote.connection.default.username", "carlos");
    props.put("remote.connection.default.password", "1234");

    Context context = (Context) new InitialContext(props).lookup("ejb:"); //failing line!!!
}
```

There are no diferences between the servers: both define the user `carlos` with the given password, Both servers run in the same machine with the same IP Address and port (not at the same time of course!)... **The only difference between them is the Wildfly Server Version!**

The application Client uses the `jboss-client.jar` according to the target wildfly...

Comment: Did you actually find a solution for your Problem? I'm having the same Issue while migrating from Jboss7 to Wildfly10 and would be interested in any solution if one exists .... (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120825/wildfly10-ejb-remote-client-no-response)

Comment: Sadly, I haven't found a solution for this ... I stop working in a solution because the problem only happens at my personal laptop (Windows 7 Professional); other environments at my work: physical workstations (windows7), Virtual Machines and docker machines (linux); don't show that weird error... I was thinking in debugging the jboss-client.jar to find the root of the problem (but, I stop working on this issue)

Comment: Thanks to your answer we got some hints which helped us get rid of the issue. It looks like there are antivirus programms which do some package vodoo and kill the client-server communictaion ... more details in my linked questions above.