# Wildfly10 - EJB-Remote Client - no response

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm currently migrating our code from Jboss7 to Wildfly10.
The Server itself starts up totaly fine.
When trying to connect our client with the working new wildfly10 server for ejb-remote calls it just won't work.
The only thing I get to work with is the following error:

> org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
>   WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to remote-ip:8080
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING  at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:94)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:118)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:291)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   de.cinovo.rcp.test.RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:39)
>     at de.cinovo.rcp.test.RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:25)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling
>   [appName:de.cinovo.tcc.server-ear,
>   moduleName:de-cinovo-tcc-server-ejb-6.0-SNAPSHOT, distinctName:]
>   combination for invocation context
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@180542f   at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   de.cinovo.rcp.test.RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:39)
>     at de.cinovo.rcp.test.RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:25)

There is no error, warning, info or anything showing up in the server log, while trying to connect.
There is some action on the port via tcp while watching during a call attempt.

The realy funny part is:
If I use the same wildfly setup on my local machine, the exact same connection method works, but only while using `localhost` as the ip address within the `jboss-ejb-client.properties`. 
As soon as I change the ip into `127.0.0.1` or my current ip address, it will fail with the same error as above.

Relevant information:

- Wildfly will respond to a telnet on port 8080
- Wildfly is the only service listening on 8080
- My /etc/hosts is correctly configured
- Changing the port doesn't fix the problem
- Wildfly Version 10.1.0.Final
- Relevant parts from my `standalone.xml`

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
      <endpoint/>
      <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
  </subsystem>
  [...]
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
      <buffer-cache name="default"/>
      <server name="default-server">
          <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
      [...]
  </subsystem>
  [...]
  <interfaces>
      <interface name="public">
          <any-address/>
      </interface>
  </interfaces>
  [...]
  <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
      <socket-binding name="http" interface="public" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
      <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
  [...]
  </socket-binding-group>
  ```
- My jboss-ejb-client.properties

  ```
  endpoint.name=client-endpoint
  remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
  remote.connections=default
  remote.connection.default.host=<host-ip>
  remote.connection.default.port=8080
  remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
  remote.connection.default.username=<usernmae>
  remote.connection.default.password=<pswd>
  ```
- Client-Code

  ```
  final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
  jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
  final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
  [...]
  return context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
  ```
- EJB-Client-Maven-Dependency :

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
      <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  ```

Anyone out there who had the same problem and knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know if there is a firewall issue? Can you telnet to the machine that you are trying to connect? try `telnet remoteip port`   if it is in trying mode for a little bit of time then the remote machine is not being recognized through firewall

Comment: As stated above, telnet is possible, so I ruled a firewall problem out. Especially since the same test server was used for an old jboss test scenario until a few days ago, which used the same ports.

Comment: This still smells like a firewall problem. Do you have one of those "smart" HTTP firewalls that does packet/header inspection? Maybe it does not support the HTTP Upgrade protocol used for HTTP remoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for everybody interested, here is the solution to my problem:
based on the [comment by Steve C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120825/wildfly10-ejb-remote-client-no-response#comment73670875_43120825) and the help of a friend, we figured out that the problem is not server based.

It appears that there are some antivirus programs, which do something with your HTTP messages, as soon as the HTTP-upgrade negotiations with the Wildfly/server are done. They seem to manipulate the sent/received packages, which leads to the problem in the client, as it is no longer able to understand the answers.
Therefore it never gets to react, since the package appears to have been lost - hence the `IoFuture` exception and EJB receiver not found.

Long story short: removing the antivirus program from our systems (in our case Bitdefender) leads to everything working as intended...

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there is a missing definition in the **standalone.xml** in the **socket.binding-group**:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="remote-ejb">
  <local-destination socket-binding-ref="http"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that hint. But unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem (just tried it). As far as I understand, this is used for EJB invocations from a remote server instance. What I'm trying to do is an EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI...