# Simple EJB client - Operation failed with status WAITING

Tags: maven, jboss, ejb, wildfly-10

I am trying to write simple client for ejb and i am getting

```
    WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to localhost:8080
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:93)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:148)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.<init>(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:105)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.<init>(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.<clinit>(EJBClientContext.java:81)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createSession(EJBClient.java:197)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.doCreateProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:187)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.createEjbProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:164)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.lookup(EjbNamingContext.java:147)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at RemoteEJBClient.lookupTheatreBookerEJB(RemoteEJBClient.java:67)
    at RemoteEJBClient.testRemoteEJB(RemoteEJBClient.java:17)
    at RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:11)

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create proxy [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000024: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:java:app, moduleName:ticket-agency-ejb, distinctName:] combination]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.createEjbProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.lookup(EjbNamingContext.java:147)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at RemoteEJBClient.lookupTheatreBookerEJB(RemoteEJBClient.java:67)
    at RemoteEJBClient.testRemoteEJB(RemoteEJBClient.java:17)
    at RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000024: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:java:app, moduleName:ticket-agency-ejb, distinctName:] combination
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:627)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createSession(EJBClient.java:199)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.doCreateProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:187)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.createEjbProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:164)
    ... 5 more
```

I have tried changing port to 4447 and 8443 but i didn't help.

I am deployig ejb using  `mvn clean install` and then `mvn wildfly:deploy` and for client `mvn install exec:exec`

I am using wildfly 10.1.0 Final but i have also tried running my app on wildfly 12.0.0 Final.

My ejb code: https://github.com/tomaboro/soa-agh-course/tree/master/lab5/lab0

My client code: https://github.com/tomaboro/soa-agh-course/tree/master/lab5/lab0_klient

Comment: These are not maven projects - there are no pom.xml files

Comment: They are here:
https://github.com/tomaboro/soa-agh-course/blob/master/lab5/lab0_klient/pom.xml
https://github.com/tomaboro/soa-agh-course/blob/master/lab5/lab0/pom.xml

Comment: You may have the same problem as this guy [wildfly10-ejb-remote-client-no-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120825/wildfly10-ejb-remote-client-no-response)

Comment: There is also more information at [standalone-jboss-ejb-client-application-how-to-get-jndi-connection-distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574751/standalone-jboss-ejb-client-application-how-to-get-jndi-connection-distinct). There is working demo related to that question on GitHub at [https://github.com/sfcoy/remote-ejb-41574751](https://github.com/sfcoy/remote-ejb-41574751)